# QGIS Field Calculator NaN error messages dependent upon variable type?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, fields-attributes, error

I have a layer which contains roads. I am using the Field Calculator to compute some statistics based on different attributes. Using QGIS 3.10.14

I am running into an issue using lengths. I have created a minimal reproducible example. Writing something like `1 / $length` generates the error message,

> Evaluation Error: An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string: Cannot convert 'nan' to double

This leads me to believe that one of the road segments has 0 length or NAN length. I stored the lengths of the roads separately using, `len = $length`

- Filtering using `len <= 0` returns no results. So I have no segments with 0 length
- Filtering using `len > 100000` returns no results. So I have no segments that have overflow length
- Filtering using `len IS NULL` returns no results. So I have no segments with missing lengths
- Filtering using `len < 0 AND 0 <= len` returns no results. So I have no segments with NAN length

I also noticed that I can get around this issue by first casting the length into an integer data type. So using `len2 = $length` where len2 is specified as **Whole number (integer)** and then doing `1 / len2` does not generate the error. Specifying the original `len` variable with **Decimal number (real)** and then doing `1 / len` does generate the error message. I would prefer to avoid using this workaround as it will lead to a loss of precision.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or what is causing it?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for testing?

Comment: Did you also check if you have $length values >0, but very near to 0?

Comment: @Babel I filtered for any length values < 1 meter and tried 1/len and it did not generate any errors. So the smallest values are not causing issues

Comment: The data set is too large. Is there a way to see exactly which entry generates the error?

Comment: Try selecting a subset of your data (like `$id<5000`) and try the expression there to see if it works.

Comment: How is the data saved (file format)? How large is it?

Comment: Try creating a boolean field with `if (1/$length >0, 1,0)` to see which entry generates the error

Comment: Have you tried filtering for NaNs?  `len = 'NaN'::real`     FYI, `select 'NaN'::real <=0` evaluates False and `select 'NaN'::real >= 0` evaluates True.  I'm not sure you were filtering correctly to find the NaNs.

Comment: Also, NaN doesn't exist in the int type, so you wouldn't see any NaNs if you're using int.